# controlling triggers in YAML for different environments in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 3 environments in Azure , Sandbox, Test and Prod.

I have yaml pipeline in azure devops which builds the infrastructure. The environment built depends on the variables in the terraform code

The same pipleline is used to deploy to all environments depending on conditions in the yaml file.I want Dev to trigger on a merge to master but only want test and prod to deploy manually. How can i set this up in the yaml file?

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops. you can add approval and that should do the trick

Comment: Hi, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

For Dev, you can set up build validation of branch 'Master':

[image]

And in the Master branch, the YML file should be like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

This can make sure the pipeline of the master branch(Dev environment) only triggers after the PR merge is completed.

For test and prod environment, you can create a branch with the same name YML that the pipeline is looking for. And use the below YML definition:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

This can make sure the test and prod only can be triggered manually.

Above solution just need one pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you can add the condition in your YAML pipeline.

> Dev to trigger on a merge to master

You can set the variable: `Build.Reason` and `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch`.

For example:

```
condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```

> want test and prod to deploy manually

You can set the variable: `Build.Reason`

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
```

YAML example:

```
stages:
  - stage: Dev
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
          - xx    
  - stage: Prod
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
    jobs:
      - job: B
        steps:
          - xx

  - stage: Test
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
    jobs:
      - job: C
        steps:
          - xx
```

When the pipeline is triggered by Pull Request and the target branch is master, the Dev stage will run.

When the pipeline is triggered manually, the Test and Prod stage  will run.

Refer to this doc: [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).